# Notify application when a notification has been received and not tapped on or dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

On iOS 10, is there any delegate to notify application that notification was not tapped on or it was cancelled?

I mean, how to get notification data even if the user has not tapped on it?

I have those two delegate methods which respond only when the user taps the notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

Comment: Keep that data in your own backend, don't rely on the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Below method will be called when notification arrives.

`func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)`

see this apple doc for further information. [Notifications apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension)

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway to modify things stored in application like Realm database through this method if the application has been terminated?

Comment: It doesn't get called if the app is terminated, but works fine if the app is in background